# Displaying initial checked value before on click checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checked

I have a jQuery script to display the checked value of a form field selection on the form page before submitting. I need to modify the script to show the default/initial checked value upon page load before a click has occurred. It should be mentioned that my checkboxes act as radio buttons, so that is not a factor here. The fiddle is here..  http://jsfiddle.net/brokenmold/8355so3o/

form html//

```
<input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck-qty" name="7in-fold-qty" value="500" id="7in-fold-qty" data-value="0" checked /> 500
<input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck-qty" name="7in-fold-qty" value="1000" id="7in-fold-qty" data-value="0" /> 1000
<input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck-qty" name="7in-fold-qty" value="2000" id="7in-fold-qty" data-value="0" /> 2000
<input type="checkbox" class="radiocheck-qty" name="7in-fold-qty" value="3000" id="7in-fold-qty" data-value="0" /> 3000
```

summary html//

```
<span class="spec-qty"></span>
```

relevant jquery//

```
$( ".radiocheck-qty" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( ".spec-qty" ).html( $( ".radiocheck-qty:checked" ).val() + " copies" );
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you using radio buttons?

Comment: Also, you should change it to `$( ".radiocheck-qty" ).on( "change"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add this line with the rest of your code. It'll change the text to "500 copies", assuming that the first checkbox is checked by default

```
$( ".spec-qty" ).html( $( ".radiocheck-qty:checked" ).val() + " copies" );
```